# Having trouble with copying struct to another memory location with memcpy()

Tags: c, struct

Okay so basically I am not sure what is happening here

I am basically trying to copy a struct variable that I defined to another memory location which I malloc'd using memcopy

the compiler does not give any errors and warnings

however when I try to access the malloc'd memory location to see if the data was copied,I find some weird numbers coming up when I dereference the pointer and not the values that I copied

here is my code , what is it exactly that I am missing here,

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#include <stdint.h>

typedef uint32_t u_int32_t;

typedef unsigned char byte;
typedef u_int32_t link;
typedef u_int32_t size;
typedef u_int32_t addr;

typedef struct header {
   u_int32_t unkno;  
   size sze;     
   link next;     
   link prev;     
} head;

int main(){

   head x;

   printf("%d %d %d %d\n", &x, &x.unkno,sizeof(head),0x12345);

   x.unkno = 0x12345;
   x.sze = 10;
   x.next = 2;
   x.prev = 6;

   void * s = malloc(sizeof(u_int32_t)*100);

   memcpy(s, (const void *)&x, sizeof(head));

   head * k = (head *)s;

   printf("%d",*(k+1));

   return 0;
}
```

so if somebody can point me to what I am doing wrong, or if this is even possible?

Comment: Your code copies the struct correctly. I don't know what you are expecting to see from `printf("%d",*(k+1));`  , this reads memory beyond the end of the struct that you just copied. Maybe you meant `printf("%d", k->unkno);` ?

Answer (score 3):

You only copy *one* structure to the 400 bytes you allocated, and `malloc` does not initialize the memory in any way.

The contents of newly allocated memory from `malloc` is *indeterminate*, and reading from the uninitialized memory leads to *undefined behavior*.

Also, when you do `*(k + 1)` you treat `k` as an array, and accessing the *second* element (`*(k + 1)` is equivalent to `k[1]`). You then do something even weirder and print the value as a decimal number, which it really isn't.

Lastly, when printing a pointer using [`printf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) you should use the `"%p"` format specifier.

---

To actually *answer* your question, then yes the data you copy is there, at the beginning of the allocated memory. You just don't print any of it.

Comment: my question wasn't related to any of the things you mentioned, i was simply trying to check that the data i copied was actually there and that i can access it and i solved the solution, it was the pointer type that wasnt correct, not all that mumbo jumbo you went on about without addressing the question i actually had

Comment: @hopjoppe5 Updated my answer. And it's *not* "mumbo jumbo", it's really important things that you need to read and understand, otherwise you will not become a master of C programming, but a master of undefined behaviors in C.

Comment: @hopjoppe5 Maybe if you had created a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) *without* all these problems it would have been easier to concentrate on what your main issue was. You *do* weird things (that `printf` call doesn't make any sense at all, the compiler should have given you a warning about it), and you *do* read uninitialized memory which is UB. And once you have even the single and slightest UB then your whole program looses all its meaning. If you know you are doing all these bad things, why not tell us that and to ignore them?

Answer (score -2):

Okay i solved this

basically it was the problem with the pointer that was accessing the malloc'd memory

it was this line that was causing me problems

```
head * k = (head *)s;
```

it should have been

```
 u_int32_t * k = (u_int32_t *)s;
```