# Printf() printing of arguments and pointers in C

Tags: c, pointers, printf

Okay so basically i am trying to understand what is happening here with printf and pointers in various forms

this is the code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct mine{
   unsigned int  memory;
   struct mine * next;
}mine;


int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

   mine * y;

   y = (struct mine *)malloc(sizeof(struct mine));
   y->memory = 0xBEEFDEAD;

   printf("%x\n",*y);
   printf("%x\n",y[0]);
   printf("%x\n",y->memory);
   printf("%x %x %x\n",y->memory, *y,y[0]);

   return 0;
}
```

and here is the output

```
beefdead
beefdead
beefdead
beefdead beefdead 7c00c0
```

as you can see the same pointers being printed give a different result with printf when they are separated individually and when they are grouped together

is this a problem with the way i am printing the pointers, or is this a problem with printf

also does *y = y[0] = y->memory

from the output i am not sure about the answer to this question

Comment: `y->memory = (unsigned int *)x; ` should at least be `y.memory = (unsigned int *)x; ` (and you should use %p for printing pointers) and `x->memory,` does not exist, since x is a void pointer. Same for `x[0]`

Comment: Please rad a C bokk or use a different one. You are doning too much wrong here, showing you really need to tget the basics right first. Your code does not even compile.

Comment: sorry guys i copied that very badly, i just got home from work and am exhausted and need sleep, so i copied it out by typing it and missed a few bits , please look at it again after refreshing

Comment: Standard warning: do not cast the result of `malloc` & friends in C!

Comment: @hopjoppe5 Your question is far from clear. We can't read your mind; we can only analyze code you post here. What you posted here is full of errors; there's no way to explain any output you may or may have gotten from your real code, which only you can see.

Comment: @hopjoppe5 Pointing out errors in code is what this site is for (among other things). It is not an "attack" on your code. It's also not an attack on *you*; you are not your code.

Comment: @melpomene if you truly found what i said to be so confusing, i dont know how you write code everyday(if you write code) but on the other hand if you couldnt understand my "confusing code" then at least meditate on the last line y->memory = y[0] =*y and give an answer based on that , does it hold true (if you know)

Comment: @hopjoppe5 `y[0]` and `*y` are the same (I already wrote that in a previous comment). `y->memory` is an `unsigned int *`, `*y` is a `struct mine`, so they're not the same.

Comment: @hopjoppe5 Passing `y->memory` to `printf` `%p` is an error: `%p` takes a `void *`, not an `unsigned int *`.

Comment: @hopjoppe5 Passing `y[0]` or `*y` (they're the same thing) to `printf` `%p` is an error: `%p` takes a `void *`, not a `struct mine`.

Comment: even if you change it to print hexadecimal value or decimal or whatever else, it still prints it, meaning that my question which was about x* = x[0] = x->memory means they all do the same thing, but for some reason in printf when they are bundled together something goes wrong, which must mean it is an issue with printf

Comment: @hopjoppe5 you are assuming (at least) `sizeof (void*) == sizeof (unsigned int)`, here. This is dangerous, especially when varargs functions are involved.

Comment: with all due respect can you just answer the question i am asking? is it so hard to answer the question? all the details are there , if you dont know , you dont know and leave it

Comment: Playing a game of morphing questions?

Comment: Listen hop, I'm not trying to defend @Olaf here just because he's a member of the community with some earned reputation (that comes from actually helping people, by the way), but I have to admit after reading some of your other "questions" that you're exceedingly good at fighting with people who are trying to help you. This one is a rather good example - http://stackoverflow.com/a/32218272/2016408

Comment: its so strange but people here they lack focus, you ask about one thing they all talk about another , and look how easy it was to solve the solution to the problem , just simply change the type while they were going on about all the irrelevant stuff , that frustrates me because it doesnt help me but derails me and causes confusion, why cant people just read the question and example i give, it seems people are not interested in helping but in criticizing, do you blame me for getting angry? i come here for answers not for further confusion and distraction

Comment: Well, that's mainly because answers in SO are meant to last and help others. If you're doing something wrong, it wont do to ignore that and help you, but confuse the heck out of anyone else reading this in the future. And if you're referring to that other question - you didn't solve it, you just replaces one UB with another. That's what he was trying to explain, but you didn't listen

Answer (score 0):

When you do this:

```
printf("%x\n",*y);
```

Or this:

```
printf("%x\n",y[0]);
```

You're feeding a `struct mine` to the `%x` format specifier.  This is undefined behavior, which means anything could happen.

In the case of your particular compiler on your particular machine, the `%x` specifier is probably picking up the first 4 bytes of the `struct mine` that's being passed in which happens to be the contents of `memory`.  But you can't depend on this behavior.  It could very well do something different if you use a different compiler or even run the same executable on a different machine.

In the case of this line:

```
printf("%x %x %x\n",y->memory, *y,y[0]);
```

The first parameter is fine and will always print what you expect.  The second parameter invokes undefined behavior as mentioned previously.  On your particular machine with your particular compiler, it prints the contents of `memory` for the second `%x` as in the prior example.  In the case of the third `%x`, it looks for the next 4 bytes on the stack.  This is not the `y[0]` you passed in but the contents of `next` from when `*y` was passed in, since a `struct mine` was passed for the second parameter which contains 8 bytes.

But again, this behavior is undefined.  It could print something entirely different if you use a different compiler, change the compiler settings, or run on a different machine.  There's no guarantee that what happened for you will always happen.

This is not an issue with `printf` as you suggested in the comments.  This is you invoking undefined behavior.

EDIT:

If you're attempting to view the *address* of `y->memory`, `*y`, and `y[0]`, you need to pass the address of each of these and use the `%p` format specifier to output them correctly:

```
printf("%p %p %p\n", (void *)&y->memory, (void *)y, (void *)&y[0]);
```

Since `y[0]` is equivalent to `*(y + 0)` (i.e. `*y`), and because `memory` is the first field of the struct, this will output three identical (system dependent) values.

Comment: hi and thanks for your time and answer,

what if i use those commands individually? 

*x or x[0] or x->memory is it fine and will not cause undefined behavior? as in the examples above the printf line which contains them all?

Comment: No, using them individually is still undefined behavior for the reasons I specified.  Just because it happened to print what you expected doesn't mean the behavior is well defined.

Comment: @hopjoppe5 Does this answer your question?

Comment: no it doesnt, because what are you saying that the code that gets executed is randomly generated by the compiler that deals with this?

Comment: The code that gets generated is not random, however the behavior of the code basically is if you're using incorrect format specifiers, i.e. reading memory you're not supposed to.  I made an edit that addresses what I believe you're trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

> is this a problem with the way i am printing the pointers

Code never attempts to print pointers.  Code attempts to print `*y`, `y[0]`, `y->memory`.  These are types `mine`, `mine`, and `unsigned`.

To print a pointer like `y`, use printf specifier `"%p"` and cast to `(void *)` if the pointer is not all ready a `void *`.

```
printf("%p\n", (void *) y);
```

To print the contents of a structure like `struct mine`, print the individual sub-fields.  See below.

Mis-matched print format specifiers with the passed augments result in behavior that is specified by the C spec to be *undefined behavior*.  The results may be anything?  Any explanation of such behavior relies on many assumptions concerning the underlying generate code and frankly is a lot of guess-work.

Use matching `printf()` format specifiers with values of the matching type.

Many compilers warn of such mis-matches.  Insure your compiler's warnings are fully enabled.  Saves you time.

---

`"%x"` matches an `unsigned`, not type `mine`.  Result: undefined behavior.

```
mine * y;
...
// printf("%x\n", *y);
// Instead:
printf("%x %p\n", y->memory, (void *) y->next);
```

Same for `printf("%x\n", y[0]);`  Result: undefined behavior.

```
// printf("%x\n", y[0]);
// Instead:
printf("%x %p\n", y[0].memory, (void *) y[0].next);
```

Same for `printf("%x\n", y[0]);`  Result: undefined behavior.

```
// printf("%x %x %x\n", y->memory, *y, y[0]);
```